# Route callbacks not executing but middleware is

Tags: node.js, express

So this project was working fine before today, but after a bit of a nooby mistake with git I broke my project, and was unable to recover the commit. After spending some time getting everything fixed, my routes are now broken. My issue is that when calling my API routes now the server hangs for exactly 1 minute, then times out and logs a 404 on the server.

To give some background I'm using [this](https://github.com/diki/nodejs-passport-boilerplate) boilerplate. In my debugging process I basically put console.logs everywhere I possibly could, and it looks like all my initialization middleware for express and passport are working fine, and my code is getting to where the routes are defined with no errors.

Middleware with `app.use` works and all checks out when a request is made, and all console.logs I've put there show fine. The console.logs only stop appearing in the final route definition like in this example:

```
app.get('/route', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('this never shows');
    next();
}, function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('this never shows');
})
```

My actual routes do have a `res.send()`, this is just an example to show you. All the console.logs I put in the middleware before this route show when the request is made, so it is hanging somewhere in `app` here.

It's a rather large project, so if you want specific code examples just ask and I'll post it. But I was able to recover all the important files that I had saved somewhere else and I'm pretty sure all my code is back to how it was before now.

edit:

Here is my file with express middleware definitions:
config/express.js

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(express);
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var helpers = require('view-helpers');
var swig = require('swig');
var session = require('express-session');

module.exports = function (app, config, passport) {

  app.set('showStackError', true);
  // should be placed before express.static
  app.use(express.compress({
    filter: function (req, res) {
      return /json|text|javascript|css/.test(res.getHeader('Content-Type'));
    },
    level: 9
  }));
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.static(config.root + '/public'));
  app.use('/uploads', express.static(config.root + '/uploads'));

  var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");

    // intercept OPTIONS method
    if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
        res.status(204).end();
    }
    else {
        next();
    }
  };

  app.use(allowCrossDomain);

  // don't use logger for test env
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') {
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  }

  // set views path, template engine and default layout
  app.engine('html', swig.renderFile);
  app.set('view engine', 'html');
  app.set('views', config.root + '/app/views');
  app.set('view cache', process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development');

  app.configure(function () {
    // dynamic helpers
    // app.use(function(req,res,next){
    //     req.locals.session = "eeeeeeee";
    //     next();
    // });

    // cookieParser should be above session
    app.use(express.cookieParser());

    // bodyParser should be above methodOverride
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());

    // express/mongo session storage
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        if(!req.cookies['_ga']) {
            next();
        }
        else {
            session({
                secret: 'secrettexthere',
                saveUninitialized: true,
                resave: true,
                store: new MongoStore({
                    url: 'mongodb://localhost/traderdb',
                    db: 'traderdb',
                    collection: 'sessions',
                    auto_reconnect: true
                })
            })(req, res, next);
        }
    });

    // connect flash for flash messages
    app.use(flash());

    app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        res.locals.session = req.session;
        res.locals.req = req;
        next();
    });
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        if(!req.cookies['_ga']) {
            next();
        }
        else {
            passport.initialize()(req, res, next);
        }
    });

    //app.use(helpers('app name'));
    //
    // use passport session
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        if(!req.cookies['_ga']) {
            next();
        }
        else {
            passport.session()(req, res, next);
        }
    });

    // routes should be at the last
    app.use(app.router);

    // assume "not found" in the error msgs
    // is a 404. this is somewhat silly, but
    // valid, you can do whatever you like, set
    // properties, use instanceof etc.
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
      // treat as 404
      if (~err.message.indexOf('not found')) return next();

      // log it
      console.error(err.stack);

      // error page
      res.status(500).render('500', { error: err.stack });
    });

    // assume 404 since no middleware responded
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      res.status(404).render('404', { url: req.originalUrl, error: 'Not found' })
    });

  })
}
```

I also have another file with passport route definitions if you'd like to see that too, but all that is tested and works okay too.

edit 2:

This is my entry point file:
server.js

```
/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var express = require('express')
  , fs = require('fs')
  , passport = require('passport');

/**
 * Main application entry file.
 * Please note that the order of loading is important.
 */

// Load configurations
// if test env, load example file
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'
  , config = require('./config/config')[env]
  , auth = require('./config/middlewares/authorization')
  , mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Bootstrap db connection
mongoose.connect(config.db);

// Bootstrap models
var models_path = __dirname + '/app/models'
fs.readdirSync(models_path).forEach(function (file) {
  require(models_path+'/'+file);
});

// bootstrap passport config
require('./config/passport')(passport, config);

var app = express();
// express settings
require('./config/express')(app, config, passport);

// Bootstrap routes
require('./config/routes')(app, passport, auth);

// Start the app by listening on <port>
var port = 3002;
app.listen(port);
console.log('Express app started on port '+port);

// expose app
exports = module.exports = app;
```

edit 3:

Here are my route definitions:
config/routes.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var fileManager = require('express-file-manager');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Session = mongoose.model('Session');

module.exports = function (app, passport, auth) {
    var users = require('../app/controllers/users');
    var coupons = require('../app/controllers/coupons');
    var magazines = require('../app/controllers/magazines');
    var zones = require('../app/controllers/zones');
    var transactions = require('../app/controllers/transactions');
    var favorites = require('../app/controllers/favorites');
    var banners = require('../app/controllers/banners');
    var reports = require('../app/controllers/reports');
    var coverContest = require('../app/controllers/coverContest');
    var contactMessage = require('../app/controllers/contactMessage');

    app.post('/api/users/login', users.login);
    app.post('/api/users/register', users.register);
    app.post('/api/users/logout', users.logout);
    app.post('/api/users/sendResetEmail', users.sendResetEmail);
    app.post('/api/users/changePassword', users.changePassword);
    app.post('/api/users/redeemCoupon', isValidAppUser(), users.redeemCoupon);
    app.get('/api/users/validate', isLoggedIn(0), function(req, res) {
        res.send(req.user);
    });

    app.post('/api/coupons', coupons.get);
    app.post('/api/coupons/import', isLoggedIn(0), coupons.import);
    app.post('/api/coupons/remove', isLoggedIn(0), coupons.remove);
    app.post('/api/coupons/upload', isLoggedIn(0), coupons.upload);

    app.post('/api/transactions', transactions.get);
    app.post('/api/allTransactions', isLoggedIn(0), transactions.getAll);

    app.post('/api/magazines', magazines.get);
    app.post('/api/magazines/import', isLoggedIn(0), magazines.import);
    app.post('/api/magazines/remove', isLoggedIn(0), magazines.remove);

    app.post('/api/banners', banners.get);
    app.post('/api/banners/import', isLoggedIn(0), banners.import);
    app.post('/api/banners/remove', isLoggedIn(0), banners.remove);

    app.post('/api/favorites', isValidAppUser(), favorites.get);
    app.post('/api/favorites/import', isValidAppUser(), favorites.import);

    app.post('/api/zones', zones.get);
    app.post('/api/zones/add', zones.add);
    app.post('/api/zones/addCoupon', zones.addCoupon);
    app.post('/api/zones/addMagazine', zones.addMagazine);

    app.post('/api/mail/ccSubmit', coverContest.ccSubmit);
    app.post('/api/mail/contactSubmit', contactMessage.contactSubmit);

    //app.get('/api/reports/siteUsers', reports.siteUsers);
    app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope: [ 'email', 'user_about_me'], failureRedirect: '/login' }), users.signin);
    app.get('/auth/facebook/callback', passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/login' }), users.authCallback);
    app.get('/auth/github', passport.authenticate('github', { failureRedirect: '/login' }), users.signin);
    app.get('/auth/github/callback', passport.authenticate('github', { failureRedirect: '/login' }), users.authCallback);
    app.get('/auth/twitter', passport.authenticate('twitter', { failureRedirect: '/login' }), users.signin);
    app.get('/auth/twitter/callback', passport.authenticate('twitter', { failureRedirect: '/login' }), users.authCallback);
    app.get('/auth/google', passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['profile', 'email'] }));
    app.get('/auth/google/callback', passport.authenticate('google', { failureRedirect: '/', successRedirect: '/main.html' }));
}

function isLoggedIn(secLvl) {
    return function(req, res, next) {
        if(req.isAuthenticated() && req.user.secLvl <= secLvl && req.user.google.email.includes('@bizpub36.com')) {
            return next();
        }

        res.redirect('https://accounts.google.com/logout');
    }
}

function isValidAppUser() {
    return function(req, res, next) {
        Session.findOne({ sess_id: req.body.sess_id }).exec(function(err, session) {
            if(!err && session) {
                next();
            }
            else {
                res.end({ status: 'error', message: 'invalid session' });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I try your route and everything is fine. The hanging caused by response nott finished yet, after the `console.log('this never shows');` add `res.json(data);` or `res.send('something');`

Comment: @emaniacs That's not my problem. If my console.logs aren't even showing then there's no way it's gonna even send a response. The callbacks aren't executing at all. That code example I gave was just an example. My actual routes do call `res.send()`.

Comment: I think, there are another route with the same name ('/route') was executed before that and finished the response. This my assumption. Check with `app._router.stack` or `router.stack`. Or put that line after your initalize your app

Comment: Another trick, add handler on `process.on('exit', exitHandler)`, throw an error in the `exitHandler`, so you can see the detail process. :)

Comment: @emaniacs Again, that was an example. I don't actually have any routes called `/route`. If you read my post, my code should be correct, it was working before.

Comment: @emaniacs So all my other middleware works, it only hangs and never executes the callbacks in the final route.

Comment: When you show us blocks of code, please tell us what files those are so we can see how they are loaded and initialized.  We need to be able to follow the loading process of each module and to do that, we need to know which files are which.

Comment: @jfriend00 Updated with filenames. Also I just installed express 4 and that broke everything, so it seems this boilerplate relies on express 3.

Answer (score 0):

If `app.use` works, my guess would be your protocol, is the `app.get` correct? You issue is otherwise located somewhere else in your code base as your sample runs fine as a single route express app.

Comment: I'm testing it by just going to it in a browser, so yes, it is get request. I'm very confused because my entire codebase was working before this git issue I had. I've tripple checked everything twice and all my code looks exactly as it did before I had this problem.

Comment: If you comment out all your other routes but this one in your code base, does it function as expected?

Comment: No, still same problem. I'm positive all my route definitions are fine because I took the file for them from an older version of the codebase and it was never really changed too much. But I've checked it over and over again still, and I'm sure  my routes are defined correctly.

Comment: So, we can figure that all your functions execute if they are not run successively as is the case when you change to `app.use`, but run one right after another there is a failure. My guess is that you have an error somewhere outside of the routers that is not hitting the console. Basically, the middleware you want to run last returns before the function with an error or no return can timeout. Does that make any sense?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like one of three things:

1. Somewhere in your middleware chain, you are not calling `next()` to allow it to advance to the next level of handlers and thus the request just eventually times out waiting for that middleware to finish (this seems to match the symptoms you describe).
2. Somehow, your `app.get()` doesn't actually match the route you expect it to or is not specified correctly.
3. You're using a router, but have not configured it correctly.

But, because you don't get an immediate 404, but rather it times out, it is probably option #1 above.

Comment: Your first option was the first thing I expected as well, but I've tested everything and my entire middleware chain executes perfectly without a hitch. I get all the way up to my last middleware definition of `app.use(app.router);`

Comment: @chrispytoes - I've never seen `app.use(app.router)`.  Usually, it would be `app.use(router)` where router is an independent object you created and then the routes on it would be `router.get()`.  So, `app.use(app.router)` does not go with `app.get()` at all.  If you want help, you will have to show us the relevant routing code.  We're guessing in the dark without access to the code.  I added option 3 (another guess without access to the code).

Comment: The `app.use(app.router)` was already written in the boilerplate I used. I've updated my post with my express middleware.

Comment: @chrispytoes - `app.use(app.router);` just looks wrong and should not be there.  Remove it.  You don't define `app.router` and it is not part a normal Express configuration.  Your actual routes should go in that spot in the sequence.  Speaking of which, where are your actual routes defined in this sequence?  If you copied this from somewhere, then you did not quite get the whole scheme.  `app.route` is not a normal way of doing things to that property like doesn't even exist unless you defined it and for it to actually work, it would have to point to a router on which you defined your routes.

Comment: That didn't do anything. Like I said, everything was working before with this. I think the boilerplate does some fancy stuff in the background that I'm not aware of, because that was always in my code and it was working before today when this issue came about.

Comment: @chrispytoes - or if `app.router` somehow exists in code we cannot see, then it is not configured properly to hook up to your routes.

Comment: @chrispytoes - Well, can't help with code we cannot see.  You've departed from the normal Express way of doing things and aren't showing us enough of the code to follow the whole routing chain in this custom implementation.  There is significant danger to using boilerplate code that you do not fully understand.  I'd recommend really trying to understand what every line of code you're using does.  It will make it a lot easier to troubleshoot when things break and easier to write solid code too.

Comment: In my original post I gave the link to the git repo for the boilerplate I used, that will give you an idea of the structure of my project.

Comment: @chrispytoes - I can find nothing in that repository that defines `app.router`, therefore I have no explanation for why `app.use(app.router)` would be correct.  Maybe I missed in the dozen+ nested directories the project is spread over, but I can't find any reason to think that is correct.

Comment: @chrispytoes - The last block of code you just added is finally the core part of your server.  How is that supposed to load your `app.get()` that you are having trouble with?  Where is that `app.get()` located?  In what file?

Comment: Is it possible that `app.use(app.router)` is syntax from an older version of express?

Comment: @chrispytoes - I have no idea.  I started with Express 4 so I don't know the older ones.  It is not mentioned in the Express 4 docs as far as I can tell.  You are using Express 4, right?

Comment: Updated post with route definitions. I'm using express 3.5.3.

Comment: @chrispytoes - Do you realize how old that is?  That's from at least 3 years ago and 4.0 was a pretty significant change (unbundling things that were previous built-in, for starters).  Most modern middleware you might grab to use in your project probably doesn't even test with Express 3 any more.  If this is an Express 3 question, then promptly put that all over the beginning of your question and I will have to opt out of helping.  I'm not sure you can even find many people here to help you with Express 3.  Why, might I ask, are you using such an old version?

Comment: So the problem caused by the incompatible version of Express with the middleware? i spend my time to install and try everything posibility :)))

Comment: @emaniacs - Is your problem now solved?  Can you finish this question by selecting a best answer?